# Making the caption & click through link more visible on a gallery photo

Tags: gallery

I need help with the standard Image Gallery in Wordpress.

My aim is to have a custom click through (to another WP page) for each photo. I have managed to do this by inserting the URL into the name of the photo. But after hyperlinking it, I can hardly see the name or the link. Please see the image attached. How do I make it more visible?

[image: A]

Answer (score 0):

You should change the color of the link with css.